# Is it possible to modify IBOutlets for subclasses?

Tags: swift, interface-builder

I have subclassed `UICollectionView` to create TileView, which is a dynamic tile view to  manage my apps layout and make it user configurable. It allows tiles to be inserted, removed and moved around.

I was considering building my own view, but figured that there is enough goodness in `UICollectionView` to transform it to what I need - but it clearly feels like I am strongarming `UICollectionView` to do something it was not designed for. However it works (quite well actually), but I ended up creating a whole suite of classes like a `TileViewDatasource`, `TileViewLayout`, `TileViewCell` which all are dependent on each other in a way.

Now if I insert a `UICollectionView` in interfacebuilder and I change the class to `TileView`, I still get the IBOutlets from `UICollectionView` - some of which are not compatible or wanted with my `TileView`.

I am not too experienced with @IBDesignables - is there any way to get rid of the original IBOutlets? I may have to pass this class on and it isn't really that intuitive. My subclass is much more specific and limited and needs way fewer configuration.

-mj

Comment: Could you give an example of IBOutlet you want to get rid of ? There should not be IBOutlets, just properties.

Comment: You can override a superclass property, not remove it.

Comment: @claude31 eg. it still shows the UICollectionView's layout which defaults to Flow, but my view had to use a TileViewLayout to work...